# From within virtual machine - how to know VMWare/VirtualBox/Hyper-V/etc is used to host it?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

From within a virtual machine, what information about host system can be obtained? E.g. I basically can `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and know something about host's CPU.

What ways do I have to get info on what platform virtualization software is used (VMWare, VirtualBox, Hyper-V and so on)? E.g. if some guest additions are used - i can see them with `lsmod`. But I don't know what modules to look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is  a package called `virt-what`, in most repos (Debian-like have it, Arch Linux has it). It is actually a shell script which will output nothing, in which case you are not in a VM, or, the authors say, inside an unknown type of hypervisor, or will output the name of the hypervisor.

It seems to know most common hypervisors. You can find more info about it [here](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/). The cute thing is that it is a shell script, thus you can easily see which test is used to establish whether the program is running inside a VM. I will not spoil your fun.

Comment: Yep. `dmidecode` output contains "VMWare" in "System Information" in my case. Good tool :)